# Difference between signing with private key using oauth2client.service_account and google.oauth2

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, cryptography, google-cloud-storage, google-oauth

I'm attempting to update my function for signing urls for Google Cloud Storage to V4. Google provides a template for this and I think I follow it until this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/signed_urls/generate_signed_urls.py#L112

```
#signer.sign() signs using RSA-SHA256 with PKCS1v15 padding
signature = binascii.hexlify(
    google_credentials.signer.sign(string_to_sign)
).decode()
```

I am currently using V2 and the oauth2client library. The code snippets for this currently are:

```
    creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_dict(service_account_creds)
    signature = binascii.hexlify(creds.sign_blob(string_to_sign)[1]).decode()
```

This doesn't seem to work however, as I am getting an error with the signature. I'm trying to reason about what's different between the two signing methods but I am having trouble. https://oauth2client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/oauth2client/service_account.html#ServiceAccountCredentials.sign_blob

There doesn't seem to be documentation in the RSA module in the docs for the google.oauth2 https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.auth.crypt.rsa.html

Comment: Which one works, and which one doesn't?

Comment: google.auth presumably, but I'd like to be able to sign using oauth2client

Comment: Could you please provide me the full error message? The GitHub sample requires to have authentication setup. Have you setup [credentials for your Function](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-python)?